# Log into proxy log file each proxy duration

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We need to log into the logs file of WSO2ESB , the duration of each call of proxy instances.
For example :
....
10:10:14,736 [MessageID : xxxxxxxxx] [duration : 259 ms]
....

It means that the proxy call associated to MessageID xxxxxxxx had a duration of 259 ms.
I don't want to active statistics mediator or BAM mediator.

Any idea to dot it easily ?
Tks
Nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SYSTEM_TIME` property which is a [Synapse Message Context Property](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Synapse+Message+Context+Properties). Using this you can get the current time in milliseconds in the desired places of the message flow and set the values as a properties. Then you can use the [Script Mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Script+Mediator) to write a small script (Javascript or Ruby) which reads the time values (stored in propeties) and do the neccessary calculations. You can display the result either in the script mediator or you can set it to a new propety so that it can be loged inside the proxy.

1. Synapse Message Context Propeties

   http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Synapse+Message+Context+Properties
2. Using Script Mediator

   http://docs.wso2.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26838871
3. Log Mediator

   http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Log+Mediator

**Following sample might help you.**

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="SampleTimeProxy"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="TIME_1"
                   expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="LONG"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
         <property name="TIME_2"
                   expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="LONG"/>
         <script language="js">var time1 = mc.getProperty("TIME_1");
              var time2 = mc.getProperty("TIME_2");
              var timeTaken = time2 - time1;
              print("--------------  " + timeTaken + " ms  -----------------");
              mc.setProperty("RESPONSE_TIME", timeTaken);
         </script>
         <log>
            <property name="time" expression="get-property('RESPONSE_TIME')"/>
         </log>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL uri="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/SimpleStockQuoteService?wsdl"/>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```